# In next.js, using css, how do I target a child element when its parents is hovered over?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

This is the css that targets the child element, "#overlay", when the parent, ".collection", is hovered.

```
.collection {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.collection:hover #overlay { 
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .3;
}
```

This is the html:

```
import styles from "./Home.module.css";

<div className={`${styles.collection} card`}>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

The properties are not applied to the child element when the parent is hovered.

Comment: What's the output of `${styles.collection}`

Comment: Do you any other element which has id `overlay`?

Comment: That is applying the .collection class from the css file into the html. The .collection class is the first segment of code shown in my question.

Comment: @kiranvj There is no other element with id=overlay

Comment: Can you check html source in browser. You div should look like this  `<div class='collection card'>` else we have a problem

Comment: @kiranvj The div looks like this <div class="Home_collection__3cOBa card">

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that by default Next.js uses [css module](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css) when importing css from Components, that means that import of css will return an object with class & id map to uglified strings.

You need to use class selector and use it on the child component.

```css
.collection {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.collection:hover .overlay { 
    // -----------^
    position: absolute;
    opacity: .3;
}
```

```js
import styles from "./Home.module.css";

<div className={`${styles.collection} card`}>
    <div id="overlay" className={styles.overlay}></div>
    // --------------------------------^
</div>
```

Comment: What if i wanna use the :checked selector in CSS, how can I do that in next js? @felixmosh

Comment: You can use `:checked` inside your css without any issue (like i did with hover)